# mysql UDF : fopen = permission denied

Tags: mysql, permissions, user-defined-functions

**EDIT**: I've re-written this question, as I got no answer and I'm currently trying to narrow the problem.

I'm trying to create a [mysql UDF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html) checking if a file exists on the server side. This function calls "open/close". It doesn't work even when the file are readeable.

I put the code for this function below:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/* The initialization function */
my_bool fileExists_init(
        UDF_INIT *initid,
        UDF_ARGS *args,
        char *message
        )
  {
  /* check the args */
  if (!(args->arg_count == 1 &&
        args->arg_type[0] == STRING_RESULT
        ))
    {
    strncpy(message,"Bad parameter expected a string",MYSQL_ERRMSG_SIZE);
    return 1;
    }
  initid->maybe_null=1;
  initid->ptr= NULL;
  return 0;
  }

/* The deinitialization function */
void  fileExists_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid)
    {
    }

#define MAX_RESULT_LENGTH 250
char *fileExists(
    UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *result,
    unsigned long *length, char *is_null, char *error)
 {
 //bad filename
 if(args->args[0]==NULL  || args->lengths[0]==0 || args->lengths[0] >= FILENAME_MAX )
    {
    strncpy(result,"#BAD_INPUT",MAX_RESULT_LENGTH);
    }
  else
    {
          char  filename[FILENAME_MAX+1];
      int err;
      int in;
      //create a NULL terminated string
      memcpy(filename,args->args[0],args->lengths[0]);
      filename[args->lengths[0]]=0;
      errno=0;
      in=open(filename,O_RDONLY|O_NDELAY);
      err=errno;
      if(in<0)
        {
        snprintf(result,MAX_RESULT_LENGTH,"#ERR:\"%s\":\"%s\".",strerror(err),filename);    
        }
      else
        {
        close(in);
        snprintf(result,MAX_RESULT_LENGTH,"OK:\"%s\".",filename);   
        }
    }
  *length=strlen(result);
  return result;
  }
```

Make:

```
gcc -Wall -DMYSQL_VERSION -fPIC -shared `mysql_config --cflags` -o `mysql_config --plugindir`/libfileexists.so udffileexists.c  `mysql_config --libs `
```

Test:

ok, mysql can open some files:

```
mysql>  create function fileExists RETURNS STRING SONAME 'libfileexists.so'; select fileExists("/etc/mysql/my.cnf"); drop function fileExists;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+---------------------------------+
| fileExists("/etc/mysql/my.cnf") |
+---------------------------------+
| OK:"/etc/mysql/my.cnf".         | 
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql>  create function fileExists RETURNS STRING SONAME 'libfileexists.so'; select fileExists("/tmp/file.txt"); drop function fileExists;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+-------------------------------+
| fileExists("/tmp/file.txt")   |
+-------------------------------+
| OK:"/tmp/file.txt".           | 
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

OK, no problem, it works, I can open() file.txt in **/tmp/**

```
ls -la /tmp 
drwxrwxrwt 16 root    root       4096 2010-05-28 15:45 .
-rw-r--r--  1 lindenb lindenb       0 2010-05-28 15:25 file.txt
```

But when I want to test a file in **/data**:

```
ls -la /data
drwxrwxrwx  4 root    root        4096 2010-05-28 16:11 .
-rw-r--r--  1 lindenb lindenb        0 2010-05-28 15:25 file.txt
```

I got:

```
mysql>  create function fileExists RETURNS STRING SONAME 'libfileexists.so'; select fileExists("/data/file.txt"); drop function fileExists;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
| fileExists("/data/file.txt")               |
+--------------------------------------------+
| #ERR:"Permission denied":"/data/file.txt". | 
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: open() returns -1 on error which happens to be -EACCESS (on OS X at least). What you probably want is strerror(errno). Can you update if that makes the reported error different?

Comment: @Paul, that's what I've done see:" strerror(err)" (I first quickly copied errno to err because using errno in a MT program is a bad practice). I also tried to use fopen rather than open. it gives the same kind of result (in==NULL). I'm running on my localhost, ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried su'ing to the user running MySQL to verify they can read that file? Your permissions look OK from reading, but its always a good check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqld was protected by [apparmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor).

> AppArmor represents one of several
>   possible approaches to the problem of
>   restricting the actions that installed
>   software can take.

I added

```
/data/** r,
```

at the end of

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

apparmor was restarted:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

and now my UDF works fine ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the file open on it? Perhaps it might be better to do it this way:

```
char *fileExists(
    UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *result,
    unsigned long *length, char *is_null, char *error)
{
 //bad filename
 if(args->args[0]==NULL  || args->lengths[0]==0 || args->lengths[0] >= FILENAME_MAX )
 {
   strncpy(result,"#BAD_INPUT",MAX_RESULT_LENGTH);
 }
 else
 {
   char  filename[FILENAME_MAX+1];
   int err;
   int in;
   struct stat statbuffer;
   //create a NULL terminated string
   memcpy(filename,args->args[0],args->lengths[0]);
   filename[args->lengths[0]]=0;
   errno=0;
   if (!stat(filename, &statbuffer)){
     if (S_ISREG(statbuffer.st_mode)){
        snprintf(result,MAX_RESULT_LENGTH,"OK:\"%s\".",filename);
     }else{
        snprintf(result,MAX_RESULT_LENGTH,"#ERR:\"%s\":\"%s\".",strerror(err),filename);
     }
   }else{
     snprintf(result,MAX_RESULT_LENGTH,"#ERR:\"%s\":\"%s\".",strerror(err),filename);
   }
 }
 *length=strlen(result);
 return result;
}
```

Instead of opening the file, use the [stat](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/stat.html), this would seem to be the reliable way of checking if the file exists, and also, it would be easier to home in on exactly why would the *stat* function fail.

Comment: I used fopen/open because my first original UDF needs to read the content of the file. Implementing 'fileExists' was just a way to narrow my problem. Thank you for you suggestion I'll try it tomorrow, it might give me some informations...

Comment: Ok, i tested this solution today, "stat" says "OK", the files exists but I still cannot read its content with "fopen"